# Recalculate markercluster and downloadUrl

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, filter, markerclusterer

I am trying to fix the problem with out success.

As you can see when you uncheck the VDSL or ADSL option the markercluster still having the same value.

```
downloadUrl("php_to_xml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var ThisMarkers = markers[i];
            var lat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
            var lng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng");
            var typeofkafao = markers[i].getAttribute("typeofkafao");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var icon = coloredRideshareIcon(typeofkafao);       
            //below is the balloon of the marker.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon
            });
            addMarker(typeofkafao, marker, map, infoWindow, ThisMarkers);
        }
        var mcOptions = {gridSize: 40, maxZoom: 15};
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map,gmarkers,mcOptions); // edo trexi
    });

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}
```

I know that the problem is on the downloadUrl function because its async.
I have to call the markerCluster outside the downloadUrl but I cant because I cant send the markers variables outside the downloadUrl function.

I think the problem is fix with something like that but not exactly like that.

```
var markers2;
downloadUrl("php_to_xml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        markers2 = markers;
    });

for (var i = 0; i < markers2.length; i++) {
    var ThisMarkers = markers2[i];
    var lat = markers2[i].getAttribute("lat");
    var lng = markers2[i].getAttribute("lng");
    var typeofkafao = markers2[i].getAttribute("typeofkafao");
    var type = markers2[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers2[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers2[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var icon = coloredRideshareIcon(typeofkafao);       
    //below is the balloon of the marker.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon
    });
    addMarker(typeofkafao, marker, map, infoWindow, ThisMarkers);
}
var mcOptions = {gridSize: 40, maxZoom: 15};
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map,gmarkers,mcOptions); // edo trexi

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}
```

Any ideas guys?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I have see the post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398881/recalculate-markercluster-onclick-of-filter
but it doesnt use downloadUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A look into the console would have been useful:

**ReferenceError: markerCluster is not defined**

the `markerCluster`-variable isn't accessible in `Markers()`

remove `var`-keyword:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map,gmarkers,mcOptions);
```